# What are the tokens used for in the Pokemon TCG online?

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

Is there a use for the tokens in the Pokemon TCG online? I have only just started playing it but happened to earn a few tokens. But when I am in the game, what can I use the tokens for? Are they used for some sort of ranking status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens are used to buy swag for your avatar in the Pokemon Trainer Club, and also when you are trading cards. They are a basic form of currency.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to 2____'s answer, they can now be used to buy booster packs or decks, for 95 and 500 tokens, respectively.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a correct answer. Although the cards you get are untradeable.

Comment: Cost 200 and 500 now

Answer (score 0):

Not they're not. As far as I can tell, all they are good for is going to pokemon.com and buying stuff for your avatar there like Ben Brocka said, but that's it. You can't use it for anything else so far. Not even  avatar gear in the Pokemon TCGO.